# Могу ли я использовать WebView в Service?

Tags: android, webview

Мне необходимо совершать некоторые операции с JavaScript на сайте, для этого я использую WebView. Могу ли я инициализировать WebView от контекста сервиса и пользоваться им в дальнейшем: ходить по сайтам, совершать операции с JavaScript? Мне не нужно выводить WebView в UI, поэтому нет никакой необходимости инициализировать WebView в activity. Я бы парсил сайт через GET-запрос, но вся проблема в использовании JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, это возможно. WebView, как и все остальные виджеты, будет работать даже если не отображать его, а просто инициализировать

Comment: а что там гугл предупреждал об использовании WebView не в UI потоке? `Warning: A WebView method was called on thread 'pool-9-thread-15'. All WebView methods must be called on the UI thread. Future versions of WebView may not support use on other threads.`

Comment: @pavel, про это не знаю, но сервис по умолчанию как раз в UI  потоке работает, так что тут эта проблема возникнуть не должна